# How to get angular app to access backend-API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

So, Ive made a backend API for a todo-app Im working on, I know that http://localhost:3000/api/todo/done is working and returns two objects, looking like this:

[{"_id":"54d6485357a52fc640bb3814","text":"Hämta tårta","completed":true},{"_id":"54d648ae57a52fc640bb3815","text":"Köpa dricka till Antons kalas","completed":true}]

Ive now written a first attempt at a frontend in angular. It all runs well in node, with no errors but I do not get any todos listed in my todo-list div. Can you please advise on this?

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- load jquery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script><!-- load angular -->
<script src="../javascripts/core.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller"mainController">
    <div class="container">

          <!-- HEADER AND TODO COUNT -->
          <div class="jumbotron text-center">
              <h1>I'm a Todo-aholic <span class="label label-info">{{ todos.length }}</span></h1>
          </div>

          <!-- TODO LIST -->
          <div id="todo-list" class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">

                  <!-- LOOP OVER THE TODOS IN $scope.todos -->
                  <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                      <label>
                          <input type="checkbox" ng-click="deleteTodo(todo._id)"> {{ todo.text }}
                      </label>
                  </div>

              </div>
          </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

ANGULAR CODE:

```
var nodeTodo = angular.module('node-todo', []);

function mainController($scope, $http) {
  $scope.formData = {};

  // when landing on the page, get all todos and show them
  $http.get('/api/todo/done')
      .success(function(data) {
          $scope.todos = data;
          console.log(data);
      })
      .error(function(data) {
          console.log('Error: ' + data);
      });
}
```

I dont even get anything printed in the console and I dont understand why...

Comment: You should put a breakpoint on the angular code, and test if $scope.todos its getting the value

Comment: You are missing your API-Base in your `http.get`; you should check your network console to see if your HTTP methods return with status 200 OK.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your angular app is correctly wired up. I don't see an `ng-app` directive in your html snippet and there is probably a typo in `ng-contoller="mainController"` (`=` is missing). Also your controller is not registered with module (but in this case it shouldn't make any difference).
Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stubb0rn/nk5xorhu/) that at least shows error message when requesting data. Hope this helps to solve your problem

Comment: Ive added the = now and it seems to work better, at least I get two checkboxes that match up with the number of todos in the database right now. However I dont get any text on the todo. Any tips?

Comment: I also see that todos are added to scope... seems to be a problem with {{ todo.text }}

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the html (note the ng-app atribute) to reference your module.

```
<body ng-app="node-todo">
<div class="container" ng-controller="mainController">
```

and then connect your controller to your app/module like this:

```
 var nodeTodo = angular.module('node-todo', []);

 nodeTodo.controller('mainController', 
  ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

     $scope.formData = {};

  // when landing on the page, get all todos and show them
  $http.get('/api/todo/done')
  .success(function(data) {
      $scope.todos = data;
      console.log(data);
  })
  .error(function(data) {
      console.log('Error: ' + data);
  });

}]);
```

Hope this helps.